# Removing old Active Directory DNS records after IP change

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, exchange-2010

I've just done a restore of a server onto a VM for testing. The server is running Windows 2008 R2 and Exchange 2010, and is a domain controller (I know, not supported).

This server is the only DC on this domain/forest at the moment.

Based on articles, I've done the following steps. Everything seems to be working mostly OK right now, but my main concern is that the internal DNS records for AD still list the old IPs, and I'm worried that DNS round-robin is going to give me some unpredictable results.

Here's what I've done so far:

- Since this is a restore, the old NIC "disappeared" and so it's a fresh NIC.
- I've added the new IP (different subnet) onto the NIC.
- Setup DNS with 127.0.0.1 as primary.
- I've edited IIS bindings.
- Ran `ipconfig /flushdns` and `ipconfig /registerdns`
- Waited 20 minutes.
- Ran `dcdiag /fix`
- Rebooted the server.
- Ran `dcdiag /fix` again.

So as I mentioned, this caused the new IP to appear, but the old IPs also remain in places list:

- domain.local / parent record
- domain.local / DomainDnsZones / parent record
- domain.local / ForestDnsZones / parent record
- _msdcs.domain.local / gc / parent record

Now, I'm sure I could go through and manually delete all of these. But, it's time consuming and inaccurate (I could miss a bunch of entries).

What's the recommended way to clean this up? Everything I've seen on domain controller IP changing, amounts to basically, "Change the IP then reboot the server".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe [Aging and scavenging](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770850.aspx) can help you out in this one.

[Don't be afraid. Just be patient.](http://blogs.technet.com/b/networking/archive/2008/03/19/don-t-be-afraid-of-dns-scavenging-just-be-patient.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. I had run into this previously when researching DC name changes, but unfortunately didn't take enough notice. The second article was particularly helpful, though I kind of went against the theme of the article and set aggresive timers, since it's just a test. Hopefully by tomorrow this will be all cleaned up.

Comment: Yes! Here's hoping! Goodluck! If all works out, feel free to mark this as your selected answer.

Comment: Will definitely mark as accepted once I've confirmed it worked out OK.

Comment: Glad we got this sorted out!